# How can I find all rows with non-letter content in an SQLite3 database table?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to write a query which searches for non-space, non-letter and non-digit characters in a column? I need to check if there are any chars like minus, apostrophes and so on.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol "has at least one letter which is not A-Z, a-z or 0-9";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this easily without regex support.  If your version of SQLite supports `REGEXP`, then it provides one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]';
```